# Workflow won't automatically start. Initiation Parameter the problem?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

My System Account is the one I used to publish the workflow. It is supposed to start when a list item is created or changed, and I've also selected allow to be started manually.

I try to test it using a non-priv. account. I can only trigger the workflow manually, however.  It doesn't start automatically.

I have Initiation Parameter on the workflow with Default Value. Could this be the problem?

Here's what the logfile says:

Declarative workflows cannot automatically start if the triggering action was performed by System Account. Canceling workflow auto-start. List Id: %s, Item Id: %d, Workflow Association Id: %s

Does this mean I can't use System Account to create and publish these workflows? should I create another privileged account just for use in creating the workflows then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the system account to execute workflows, this has been the case since 2007 Service Pack 2.

Comment: I am NOT. I used the system account to CREATE the workflows. I am using my personal non-priv account to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was - I was logged in on my test machine as System Account.  I don't know how it did that but kept going it 'automatically'. I just logged out and then back in as user account and it was fine.